# Lembrar o estado do item com cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

https://jsfiddle.net/kmvo2wum/

Eu queria que, caso o user abrisse um dos items principais, ao dar refresh, continuasse aberto.
Já tentei fazer isso de algumas maneiras mas ainda não consegui, se alguém poder ajudar, agradeço.

Comment: O único modo de fazer isso é se ao clicar, você passar por querystring algum valor e ao carregar pegar esse valor e abrir a ABA que gerou o item da query string, compreendeu?